# curl/curl.h on Windows

Tags: curl, libcurl, dev-c++

I have the following in my c++ script:

`#include "curl/curl.h"`

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

> \Users\username\Desktop\Temp\talkbot\main.cpp C:\Users\username\Desktop\Temp\talkbot\C curl.h: No such file or directory.

So I searched around and tried to download cURL for windows. I ended up on http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.21.3 and choose Download without SSL. I downloaded it and I simply got curl.exe.

What am I supposed to do with that file to get curl.h? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of downloading cURL, downloab libcurl. For Windows, you can use these links:

http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip

http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32.zip

Comment: What do I do with the zip file?

Comment: 404 Not found for the first link

Comment: These links is unavailable. To download older versions, please, follow this link: https://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/rm/7.39.0/dist-w32/ 
In my case, I used the "curl-7.39.0-devel-mingw32.zip" on Windows 10. I used this code to install `gem install curb --platform=ruby -- --with-curl-lib=C:/curl-7.39.0-devel-mingw32/bin --with-curl-include=C:/curl-7.39.0-devel-mingw32/include
`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required files in the source archive on the cURL website:

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I bumped this answer now (2014) and some links are outdated.

For all general info (all platforms) you can start to read at http://curl.haxx.se

There is a download wizard helping to choose the most actual and relevant file or binary at the moment http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/. For answering this question "libcurl" is to be chosen in the wizard. At the moment win64 only seems to be available in cygwin version, so go for win32 until this might change.

Answer (score 0):

Found this link to be helpful

https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Choose zip files for Windows

Choose tar.gz files for linux machines

Answer (score 0):

FEB 1 2021,
I had the same issue while building the source code of 3d slicer. I found that there are two directories of curl in my system (one installed by me in the path C:\Program Files (x86) and the other folder was in the source code I have downloaded for the project). primarily, the CMake takes the path of the first folder instead of the second folder.

solution: I created the environmental variable "curl_dir" (the folder containing header files of curl) and re-built it.
note: the created environment variable is the name in the cmakelists.txt in the source code folder.